# Infinitiv Komma bei einem Wort

Tags: infinitive, comma

Ich bin mir wirklich nicht sicher, ob ich bei den folgenden beiden Satzanfängen ein Komma setzen muss oder nicht. Google zeigt Quellen an, die ein Komma setzen und welche die keins setzen.

> Ziel des Tests ist es [,] herauszufinden, ob...
>
> Der Test hat das Ziel [,] herauszufinden, ob...

Mit Komma sieht der Satz ein wenig komisch aus, aber vielleicht kann mich jemand aufklären?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Rechtschreibregeln (§75) nennen folgende Grundsätze für Kommasetzung bei Infinitiven:

Komma ist zu setzen bei

1. *die Infinitivgruppe ist mit um, ohne, statt, anstatt, außer, als eingeleitet*
2. *die Infinitivgruppe hängt von einem Substantiv ab*
3. *die Infinitivgruppe hängt von einem Korrelat oder einem Verweiswort ab (siehe § 77(5))*

In allen anderen Fällen ist das Komma optional.

Bei dir ist im ersten Beispielsatz (3) der Fall, (das "es" ist das *Korrelat oder Verweiswort*), im zweiten (2) das Komma ist also jeweils zwingend.

Comment: Alles klar, danke!

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke, es muss ein Komma gesetzt werden. "Es" ist ein hinweisendes Wort, das ein Komma verlangt. Im zweiten Beispiel bezieht sich der darauf folgende Satzteil auf das "Ziel", also muss wieder ein Komma stehen.